# Los datos del recyclerview en un fragment no coinciden con los del ViewModel después de navegar a otro fragment y volver al fragment del recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, viewmodel

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación utilizando MVVM.

Y básicamente hasta ahora cuento con una actividad y 2 fragmentos.

- Un fragmento que es `ListCardFragment` contiene un recyclerview, que es donde se muestran los datos traidos de un API con retrofit.
- Otro Fragmento que es fragmento de detalle al hacer click sobre un elemento en el recyclerview `CardInfoFragment`.

A medida que se hace scroll en el recyclerview se cargan más datos y se muestran en pantalla, hasta ahí todo normal, se cambia la configuración de orientación y siguen mostrándose los datos correctamente en `ListCardFragment`.

**Después del cambio de orientación, si se hace click en un elemento del recyclerview** se navega a `CardInfoFragment` y se muestra ese fragment, cuando se regresa de `CardInfoFragment` a `ListCardFragment` faltan datos por mostrarse en el recyclerview, y cuando se hace el scroll, se cargan esos datos antiguos más los nuevos.

¿Cómo puedo retener los datos antiguos en el recyclerview después del cambio de orientación y la navegación a otro fragmento?

Adjunto el código de mi `MainActivity`, ,`CardAdapter (Adaptador de mi recyclerview)`, `ListCardFragment`, `CardInfoFragment` y mi implemetnación de `ViewModel`

**`MainActivity`**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainCardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private val viewModel: CardViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var searchView: SearchView
    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_card)
        initToolbar()
    }
    
    private fun initToolbar() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar.also {
            searchView = it.findViewById(R.id.searchView)
        })
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_1) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph))
        searchView.apply {
            isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
            setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                    viewModel.setQuerySearch(query.trim().lowercase(), true)
                    return true
                }
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                    viewModel.setQuerySearch(newText.trim(), false)
                    return true
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    fun startDetailFragment(card: Card) {
        viewModel.onClickCard(card)
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_listCardFragment_to_cardInfoFragment)
    }
    
    fun clearFocus() = searchView.clearFocus()
    
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu)
        return true
    }
    
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
    
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.advanced_search_options -> true
            R.id.my_decks_option -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

**`CardAdapter`**

```
class CardAdapter(private val cards: MutableList<Card>, private val onCLick: (Card) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {
    
    private val picasso = Picasso()
    
    fun addListCard(cards: List<Card>) {
        val position = itemCount
        this.cards.run {
            addAll(cards.filter {
                !contains(it)
            })
        }
        notifyItemRangeInserted(position, cards.size)
    }
    
    fun addFilterList(filterCards: List<Card>) {
        cards.run {
            val lastItemCount = itemCount
            clear()
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, lastItemCount)
            val positionStart = itemCount
            cards.addAll(filterCards)
            notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
        }
    }
    
    class CardViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        
        val contextActivity: Context
        val cardView: CardView
        val imageCard: ImageView
        val cardName: TextView
        val typeCard: TextView
        val raceCard: TextView
        
        init {
            with(view) {
                contextActivity = context
                cardView = findViewById(R.id.cardViewItemCard)
                imageCard = findViewById(R.id.imageViewCard)
                cardName = findViewById(R.id.textViewCardName)
                typeCard = findViewById(R.id.textViewTypeCard)
                raceCard = findViewById(R.id.textViewRaceCard)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder =
        CardViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_item_card, parent, false)
        )
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.apply {
            cards[position].let { card ->
                cardName.text = card.name
                typeCard.text = card.type.toString()
                raceCard.text = card.race.toString()
                picasso.setImageFromUrlInImageView(
                    card.card_images[0].imageUrlSmall,
                    imageCard
                )
                var currentColor: Int = Color.WHITE
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        contextActivity, (card.type.color).also {
                            if (it == R.color.colorSynchronyMonster) currentColor = Color.BLACK
                        }
                    )
                )
                cardName.setTextColor(currentColor)
                typeCard.setTextColor(currentColor)
                raceCard.setTextColor(currentColor)
                itemView.setOnClickListener { onCLick(card) }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = cards.size
    
}
```

**`ListCardFragment`**

```
class ListCardFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private val viewModel: CardViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: CardAdapter
    private lateinit var messageSearch: TextView
    private val activity by lazy {
        requireActivity() as MainCardActivity
    }
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_card, container, false)
    
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        messageSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSearch)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCard)
        recyclerView.apply {
            this.adapter =
                CardAdapter(
                    viewModel.mainList.value!!.ifEmpty {
                        viewModel.getListRandomCards()
                        mutableListOf()
                    }.toMutableList(), activity::startDetailFragment
                ).also {
                    this@ListCardFragment.adapter = it
                }
            addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                    activity.clearFocus()
                    if (viewModel.currentQuery.isNotEmpty()) return
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(RecyclerView.VERTICAL))
                        viewModel.getListRandomCards()
                }
            })
        }
        
        viewModel.mainList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { adapter.addListCard(it) }
        
        viewModel.filterListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { adapter.addFilterList(it) }
        
        viewModel.isSearching.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            messageSearch.apply {
                isGone = it
                text = resources.getString(R.string.search_message)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        activity.clearFocus()
        with(resources.configuration.orientation) {
            if (this == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
            else if (this == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        }
    }
    
}
```

**`CardInfoFragment`**

```
class CardInfoFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private val viewModel: CardViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var card: Card
    private lateinit var atkText: TextView
    private lateinit var defText: TextView
    private lateinit var levelText: TextView
    private lateinit var imageCard: ImageView
    private lateinit var cardName: TextView
    private lateinit var textAttribute: TextView
    private lateinit var textBanOCG: TextView
    private lateinit var textBanTCG: TextView
    private lateinit var textScalePendulum: TextView
    private lateinit var textArchetype: TextView
    private lateinit var layout: ConstraintLayout
    private lateinit var bitmap: Deferred<Bitmap>
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_info, container, false)
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        card = viewModel.currentCard.value!!
        bitmap = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            URL(card.card_images[0].imageUrl).getBitmap()
        }
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.mainScroll).apply {
            post {
                scrollTo(0, 0)
            }
            setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), card.type.color.also {
                    view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewNameCard).apply {
                        text = card.name
                        setTextColor(
                            if (it == R.color.colorSynchronyMonster)
                                Color.BLACK
                            else
                                Color.WHITE
                        )
                    }
                })
            )
        }
        atkText = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAtk)
        defText = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDef)
        levelText = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewLevelMonster)
        imageCard = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFullCard)
        cardName = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameCard)
        textAttribute = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttribute)
        textArchetype = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewArchetype)
        textBanOCG = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewBanListOCG)
        textBanTCG = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewBanListTCG)
        textScalePendulum = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewScale)
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewId).text = "$id"
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewDescription).text = card.description
        
        card.archetype?.let {
            textArchetype.text = it
        } ?: kotlin.run {
            textArchetype.isGone = true
            if (card is SpellTrapCard) {
                (ConstraintSet()).run {
                    layout = view.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutInfoCard)
                    clone(layout)
                    val idGuideline = R.id.guidelineDivider1
                    connect(textBanOCG.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, idGuideline, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
                    connect(textBanTCG.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, idGuideline, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
                    applyTo(layout)
                }
            }
        }
        
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewType).setIconAndText(card.type)
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewRace).setIconAndText(card.race)
        card.format?.let {
            it.banTCG?.let { TCG -> textBanTCG.setIconAndText(TCG) } ?: textBanTCG.apply {
                isGone = true
            }
            it.banOCG?.let { OCG -> textBanOCG.setIconAndText(OCG) } ?: textBanOCG.apply {
                isGone = true
            }
        } ?: kotlin.run {
            textBanOCG.isGone = true
            textBanTCG.isGone = true
            (ConstraintSet()).run {
                layout = view.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayoutInfoCard)
                clone(layout)
                connect(
                    R.id.textViewDescription,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    if (card is SkillCard)
                        R.id.guidelineDivider1
                    else
                        R.id.guidelineDivider2,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
                )
                applyTo(layout)
            }
        }
        
        if (card is MonsterCard) {
            val monsterCard = card as MonsterCard
            atkText.text = "${monsterCard.attack}"
            monsterCard.defense?.let { defText.text = "$it" } ?: defText.apply { isGone = true }
            levelText.apply {
                lateinit var text: String
                setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    0, 0, 0, when (monsterCard.type) {
                        MonsterType.XYZ_MONSTER,
                        MonsterType.XYZ_PENDULUM_EFFECT_MONSTER -> {
                            text = getString(R.string.level_info, monsterCard.level)
                            R.drawable.level_xyz_monster_s
                        }
                        MonsterType.LINK_MONSTER -> {
                            text = getString(R.string.linkval_info, monsterCard.level)
                            R.drawable.linkval_s
                        }
                        else -> {
                            text = getString(R.string.level_info, monsterCard.level)
                            R.drawable.level_monster_s
                        }
                    }
                )
                this.text = text
            }
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewAttribute)
                .setIconAndText(monsterCard.attribute)
            monsterCard.scaleOfPendulum?.let {
                textScalePendulum.text = getString(R.string.pendulum_scale, it)
            } ?: textScalePendulum.apply {
                isGone = true
            }
            
        } else {
            atkText.isGone = true
            defText.isGone = true
            levelText.isGone = true
            textAttribute.isGone = true
            textScalePendulum.isGone = true
        }
        
        MainScope().launch {
            imageCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap.await())
        }
    }
    
    private fun TextView.setIconAndText(value: Enum) {
        this.apply {
            setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                0, 0, 0, value.icon
            )
            val textToShow = if (text.isEmpty()) "$value" else "$text $value"
            text = textToShow
        }
    }
    
    private fun URL.getBitmap(): Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openStream())
    
}
```

**`ViewModel`**

```
@HiltViewModel
class CardViewModel @Inject constructor(private val service: CardProvider) : ViewModel() {
    
    private var loading =
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY, block = {})
    private var isSubmit = false
    private val searchData: MutableMap<String, List<Card>> = mutableMapOf()
    
    private val mainListLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<Card>> = MutableLiveData(emptyList())
    val mainList: LiveData<List<Card>> get() = mainListLiveData
    
    private val clickedCard: MutableLiveData<Card> = MutableLiveData()
    val currentCard: LiveData<Card> get() = clickedCard
    
    private val currentQueryLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val currentQuery: String
        get() {
            return currentQueryLiveData.value.orEmpty()
        }
    
    fun setQuerySearch(query: String, isSubmit: Boolean) {
        this.isSubmit = isSubmit
        currentQueryLiveData.value = query
    }
    
    val filterListLiveData: LiveData<List<Card>> =
        Transformations.switchMap(currentQueryLiveData) { query ->
            liveData<List<Card>> {
                if (loading.isActive) return@liveData
                if (!isSubmit) {
                    searchData[query]?.let { emit(it); return@liveData }
                    mainList.value?.filter {
                        it.name.contains(query, true)
                    }?.also {
                        isSearchingLiveData.postValue(it.isNotEmpty())
                        emit(it)
                        return@liveData
                    }
                }
                isLoadingLiveData.postValue(false)
                isSearchingLiveData.postValue(true)
                searchData[query]?.let {
                    isLoadingLiveData.postValue(true)
                    emit(it)
                    return@liveData
                }
                service.searchCard(query)?.let {
                    if (it.isNotEmpty())
                        searchData[query] = it
                    isLoadingLiveData.postValue(true)
                    emit(it)
                }
            }
        }
    
    private val isLoadingLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean> get() = isLoadingLiveData
    
    private val isSearchingLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    val isSearching: LiveData<Boolean> get() = isSearchingLiveData
    
    
    fun getListRandomCards() {
        if (loading.isActive) return
        loading = viewModelScope.launch {
            isLoadingLiveData.postValue(false)
            service.getListRandomCards()?.let {
                mainListLiveData.value = (mainListLiveData.value!!.plus(it))
            }
            isLoadingLiveData.postValue(true)
        }
    }
    
    fun onClickCard(card: Card) {
        clickedCard.value = card
    }
    
    override fun onCleared() {
        CardProvider.isInit = false
        super.onCleared()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no implementas [la biblioteca de Paging de Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview)? Ya estás implementando MVVM, y Paging es una de las bibliotecas de lo que se ha venido a llamar [*Componentes de Arquitectura*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle?hl=es-419), de la cual MVVM también es parte. Todos esos componentes trabajan mejor juntos, teniendo como resultado final una App optimizada en todos los sentidos, aparte de la facilidad con que se hacen tareas verdaderamente complejas.

Comment: A.Cedano. Leeré la documentación, ¡gracias!